# $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} \right) \,dm(x) = \int_X |f(x)|^2 \,dm(x)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fake-proofs

**Question.** *Let $(X, M, m)$ be an arbitrary measure space. Let $f \in L^1_m(X)$. Then
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} \right) \,dm(x) = 0.$$*

---

**Solution.**

Observe that $$n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} \right) \leq n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|}{n} \right)^2 = 2n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|}{n} \right) \leq 2n \frac{|f(x)|}{n} = 2|f(x)|.$$

Then $n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} \right)$ is dominated by $2|f(x)|$.

Moreover, we have

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} \right)}{1/n} = \frac{0}{0}.$$

So we apply L'Hopital's Rule and we obtain:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} \right)}{1/n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{-|f(x)|^2}{n^2} (-n^2)}{ 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} } = |f(x)|^2.$$

Then by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, we conclude that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} \right) \,dm(x) = \int_X |f(x)|^2 \,dm(x).$$

---

Where is the proof wrong? Thanks.

---

**Added Later.** I found the mistake: $n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} \right) \leq n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|}{n} \right)^2$ is not true for all $n$. As @did suggested, dominating function should be $|f|^2$.

Comment: Your title does not seem to be correct, since the limit is not $0$ but the integral of $|f|^2$.

Comment: And please replace every $dm$ by $dm(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g_n=n\log(1+|f|^2/n)$, then $\log(1+t)\leqslant t$ for every $t$, hence $g_n\leqslant|f|^2$. If $f$ is in $L^2$, this shows that $(g_n)$ is dominated. Since $g_n\to|f|^2$ pointwise, one gets $\int\limits_Xg_n\to\int\limits_X|f|^2$.

If $f$ is not in $L^2$, let $A(C)=\{|f|\leqslant C\}$ for some $C\gt0$, then $g_n\geqslant n\log(1+|f|^2/n)\mathbf 1_{A(C)}$. Furthermore, $\log(1+t)\geqslant t\log2$ for every $t\leqslant1$ hence, for every $n\geqslant C^2$, $g_n\geqslant(\log2)|f|^2\mathbf 1_{A(C)}$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_Xg_n\geqslant\int\limits_{A(C)}(\log2)|f|^2$. This holds for every $C$ and $\int\limits_{A(C)}|f|^2$ can be made as large as one wants hence $\int\limits_Xg_n\to+\infty$.

Comment: Your $n\log(1+|f|^2/n)\leqslant2|f|$ is wrong.

Comment: Then the question is not correct? I mean, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} \right) \,dm \neq 0.$

Comment: Absolutely. (Except if $f=0$ almost everywhere.)

Comment: If $f$ is not in $L^2$, the the limit is still $\int_X|f|^2=+\infty$.

Comment: By the way, what is wrong with $n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} \right) \leq 2|f(x)|$?

Comment: Try $|f(x)|=n$.

Comment: OK, I got it. $n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|^2}{n} \right) \leq n \log \left( 1 + \frac{|f(x)|}{n} \right)^2$ is not true for all $n$.